# Why is “follow with her eyes” translated as “suivre des yeux” and not “suivre de ses yeux”?

Tags: traduction, possessif, contractions

Where does the “her” go. The phrase “Following me with her ears” would be translated as “Elle me suit avec ses oreilles”. But, the possessive pronoun “ses” is nowhere to be found when “des” is used instead of “avec”.

Comment: Je ne comprends pas pourquoi le titre de la question parle de yeux, et le corps de la question parle des oreilles ?

Comment: @yagmoth555 I already got my answers. If you don’t understand the question, then don’t answer or comment.

Comment: Well, why you use eye in the title and ears in the question ? The first expression is widely used, the other not at all. Its a simple question btw, dont be rude for that

Comment: @yagmoth555 With eyes one should use “des” but with ears it seems one should use “avec ses”. So, my question was why wouldn’t one use “ses” with “des”, which is to say why is “ses” omitted when “de” is used to mean “with”. “Ears” were used to give an example where something other than “eyes” is used. I thought it’s only when we refer to “eyes”, we omit the possessive pronounce following “with”. Later, from the answers I found out that this is the case with all human body parts.

Comment: Ah, thanks for the info :)

Answer (score 4):

First, let's address this assumption:

> The phrase “Following me with her ears” would be translated as “Elle me suit avec ses oreilles.”

That sentence sounds kind of comical to me. I almost imagine her carrying her ears as she follows me around.

The idiomatic translation supplied by jlliagre still uses the definite article:

> Elle me suit à l'oreille.

...that is, if following people with ears were something we talked about more often in the first place. :)

---

But on to your question. The key idea is that **French prefers *le* [body part] over *son* [body part]**.

> Elle a les cheveux bruns.
>
> Il a la tête qui tourne.
>
> [J'ai la tête qui éclate.](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=lINnQflCeDc)

You could argue that this is short for *les* [body parts] *à* [owner]. This becomes clear in pronominal verbs:

> Je me brosse les dents à 7h30 chaque jour. *(les dents à moi = mes dents)*
>
> Il s'est cassé le bras hier. *(le bras à lui = son bras)*
>
> Elle s'est fait couper les cheveux. *(les cheveux à elle = ses cheveux)*

But such an analysis isn't necessary for understanding or speaking correctly, and importantly, substituting those extrapolations for the definite article will yield less idiomatic French.

This doesn't answer the ultimate "why", but it should at least demonstrate that *suivre des yeux* is aligned with the usual pattern.

Comment: One explanation I often heard from teachers as a child (because young native speakers tend to spontaneously say things like "j'ai brossé mes dents"): the logic (at least in French) dictates that in phrases that mention one's body parts, the context makes it obvious that the speaker is talking about their own body parts, and not someone else's, hence the mention of the "owner" is redundant and should be avoided.

Comment: For some reason, French prefer a single ear in these contexts: *Elle me suit à l'oreille* or *elle me suit d'une oreille attentive/distraite*.

Comment: @jlliagre Thanks; replaced mine.

Comment: And apart from the improved syntax, wouldn't it be "elle me suit avec **les** oreilles" rather than "**ses** oreilles" ?

Comment: @Still_learning And if my grandma had wheels, she'd be a bike, as they say in Italy :) But yeah, I agree: if we were to use that syntax, we'd still want *les*.

Comment: @jlliagre —  « Elle me suit à l'oreille » comme « l’oreille musicale » font référence à l’oreille interne, le couple d’organes capables de dire d’où vient le bruit et le danger éventuel, ce qui nécessite deux pavillons auditifs distincts. L’oreille est l’organe de l’ouïe qui permet d’entendre, les oreilles sont les instruments de cet organe

Comment: @Personne Hmouais... Je ne sais pas si on n'a qu'une oreille interne et si ça joue vraiment ici. Comme on dit *c'est agréable à l'oreille*, on dit aussi *c'est agréable à l’œil* mais on n'a pas d'œil interne unique qui justifierait ce singulier.

Comment: @jlliagre — Il est plus naturel et facile de dire ce que l’on perçoit que ce que l’on conçoit : oreille = audition, œil = vision, cela remonte à la prime enfance qui vit hors des concepts et continue chez les artistes qui s’intéressent aux vibrations lumineuses ou sonores.

Answer (score 1):

### La traduction n'est pas idiomatique

La phrase n'est pas courante et son sens n'est pas compréhensible aisément. Pouvez-vous utiliser les oreilles de quelqu'un d'autre ?

#### À éviter (saugrenu)

- « Elle me suit des oreilles. »

Les yeux peuvent se déplacer, suivre le mouvement, contrairement aux oreilles. On n'utilise pas le groupe nominal « avec ses yeux » sûrement parce que la vue dépend essentiellement des yeux.

Le choix d'une préposition ne semble pas évident mais l'usage de l'article contracté « des » pourrait se percevoir comme un COI.

> Elle tape du pied.

#### Remarque :

Sachez qu'au préalable on reconnaît les divers groupes avec la syntaxe.

[image: circular scheme]

On voit clairement dans le schéma ci-dessus que « des » à le rôle d'une préposition (article contracté).

### Le complément de verbe

Le sens change par rapport au contexte ; certains compléments sont indissociables du verbe.

À mon avis, « de ses yeux » pourrait être un complément de phrase tandis que « des yeux » semble être un complément de verbe. Les deux groupes de mots seraient des compléments circonstanciels.

#### Exemple

Voyons deux phrases ayant une signification équivalente.

- « Je m'en vais » signifie « je vais ailleurs ».
- « Je pars » signifie « je ne reste pas ici ».

Par contre, on ne retrouve aucun sens dans la phrase « Je vais » parce qu'il manque un complément de verbe.

Comment: On peut suivre à l'oreille, en particulier si on est aveugle, mais pas que. *En France, au contraire, les chiens sont la plupart du temps sous bois, on les suit à l'oreille, ne les voyant qu'au passage des routes; cependant, le travail de chasse proprement dit y est infiniment plus intéressant.* René de baron Dorlodot, *Souvenirs*, 1947. *Le pilote de la première machine modère encore sa vitesse. Je le suis à l'oreille, l'imagine dans son inspection complète du parking lorsqu'il pousse son moteur pour se rendre d'une épave à l'autre...* Jean-Luc Le Pogam, *Les Mange-Rêve*, 2019.

Comment: Pas plus ou pas moins que dans la phrase: *On peut suivre des yeux*. Mon commentaire  concernait la phrase: *Les yeux peuvent se déplacer, suivre le mouvement, contrairement aux oreilles.* Les oreilles peuvent tout à fait localiser l'origine d'un son, sans qu'il y ait d'ailleurs besoin de les bouger.